# clojure - add item to nested set

Tags: clojure

Say I have a set like this:

```
#{#{"a"} #{"b"} #{"c"}}
```

Say I wanted to updated the middle set to make s become:

```
#{#{"a"} #{"be"} #{"c"}}
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by the "middle" set? The one that contains "b"? Or the one that happens to print in the middle?

Comment: the one that contains b is what I mean

Comment: And then the next question is "what do you mean by "update". It's fairly easy to take the set in question, create a new set from it which doesn't contain the `#{b}`, then take *that* set and create yet another set with `#{be}` added. However, all pre-existing references to the first set would still see it unchanged. If you want to change the original set so that the `#{b}` is replaced by `#{be}` and is seen as such by all pre-existing references, that's a different (and more complex) question.

Comment: @BobJarvis The only thing you can change is what a reference refers to: the outcome of `@form` / `(deref form)`. You can change neither the identity of a reference nor the identity of what it happens to refer to at any time.

Comment: Why do all your nested sets have a single element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(-> #{#{"a"} #{"b"} #{"c"}} (disj #{"b"}) (conj #{"be"}))

=> #{#{"a"} #{"be"} #{"c"}}
```

(of course there's no ordering in sets, it could well be shown in any order).